# Replace pattern in URL through f3-Routing engine

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, fat-free-framework

I working on a flat-file-based project and I try to remove specific pattern from URL. The content is stored in a "content"-directory with markdown-files. I want sortable content-folder-names like:

---

**contentfolder**:

```
- 01-home

  - 01-subpage

  - 02-subpage2

- 02-page02

  - 01-subpage

  - 02-subpage2
```

etc...

At the moment, the URL would look something like this:

```
http://domain.com/01-home/02-subpage
```

---

This is really ugly ;)

I would prefer to get the url work as follows:

```
http://domain.com/home/subpage
```

I would prefer a solution, which works for every case of url:

```
http://domain.com/home/subpage/subsubpage/subsubsubpage
```

etc.

---

My script use at the moment the f3-Wildcard-Solution (GET /*). The requested URL will be replaced to get the content.

```
function find($path = "") {

    $dirname = str_replace(globals::root(), "", globals::current());
    if ($dirname == "/") {
        $this->location = globals::content() . globals::home() . "/" . $path;
    } else {
        $this->location = globals::content() . $dirname . "/" . $path;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you clarify what is the meaning of the numeric index in front of each file/folder?

Comment: of course. This numbers are only for contentfolders not for files. I want to give the articles or pages a simple orderfunction. Similar to staceyapp or kirby cms.

Comment: Another question, is it possible to clean the url with mod_rewrite via a regex-pattern? My htaccess-file is the standard f3-htaccess. My idea was to use this pattern `^([0-9])+\w-` to remove the numbers and the hyphen, but honestly I have no clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: why don't you simple put a meta file in the parent folder where do define the ordering of its child-directories!?

Comment: hey ikkez, I thought already about to put a number for sorting like this but unfortunally it is not userfriendly ;) I want to give the user a better overview of the pages with this numbers.

Comment: you could also use a JIG mapper for handling the pages and it's sorting. JIG is also flat-file. no DB needed.

Comment: imagine you want to reorder some page, but have 20+ pages/folders to rename now. not very user-friendly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, assuming that:

- your markdown files are located in a `content/` folder
- every subfolder is prefixed with two digits and a hyphen (XX-something)

=>

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');

$f3->set('CONTENT','content/');//location of markdown files

$f3->route('GET /*',function($f3,$params){
  $path=str_replace('..','',$params[1]);//security
  $dirs=glob($f3->get('CONTENT').'??-'.str_replace('/','/??-',$path));
  if ($dirs) {
    $dir=$dirs[0];//pick first match
    echo \Markdown::instance()->convert($dir.'/default.md');
  } else
    $f3->error(404);
});

$f3->run();
```

Comment: hey xfra35, this is not exactly what I'm looking for but I should try it ;). The thing I forget to mention, that the md-files should be in this folders because, there could be other files too, like images and the md-filename is the same like the template name. The system should get the url by the folders und the template by the name of the md-file. Example: http://page.com/about contains the default.md which renders the default.php in template.

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer. But now, your structure looks very similar to the one of fatfreeframework.com. You can find its code [here](https://github.com/F3Community/F3com). Maybe it will help.